# Setting up kernel keyboard mapping

Tags: linux, kernel, acpid

I already got the keycode from kernel, but `acpi_listen` won't recognize it in Arch Linux:

```
# /usr/lib/udev/keymap -i /dev/input/by-path/platform-thinkpad_acpi-event
Press ESC to finish, or Control-C if this device is not your primary keyboard
scan code: 0x1A    key code: micmute
```

Now I try to map the key by:

```
# /usr/lib/udev/keymap /dev/input/by-path/platform-thinkpad_acpi-event 0x01a micmute
setting scanode 0x1A to key code 248
```

But `acpi_listen` still got no output here.

How should I make `acpi_listen` recognize it?

**UPDATE2**

Well , evdev driver doesn't seem to recognize this , I heard someone saying that xorg won't route key event number that went beyond the limit..

It has to be solved as a acpi event , but don't know how

**UPDATE**

Seems to be complicated,

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 248 = XF86MicMute NoSymbol XF86MicMute'
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym name 'XF86MicMute' in keysym list
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym name 'XF86MicMute' in keysym list
xmodmap:  2 errors encountered, aborting.
```

Comment: [Maybe this helps you, at least gaining insights](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=757365#c1)  (and as this progably won't be fixed soon, [a workaround](http://www.fedoraforum.de/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21920#p123046); German, but probably self-explanatory)

Comment: [Found an English post describing the workaround](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1536096&postcount=7) (I don't see any reason for this not to work in Ubuntu).

Comment: @sr_ I found that long time ago , and it doesn't work on Arch Linux ..

Comment: The keycode `248` is simply not mapped because `248+8>255`, the hard-coded limit...  So to workaround you first have to *change this* on a lower level before `xmodmap` is of any use.

Comment: @sr_ i forget to reboot to make those changes effects , it worked indeed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that key code `micmute` is out of range, as explained [in this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=757365#c1).  So you need to remap scan code 0x1A to some other key code you are not using that is in range.  If [this workaround](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1536096&postcount=7) using `prog2` doesn't work you have to pick some other key code.  You can look in [`/usr/include/linux/input.h`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) to see which key codes are defined and then [look at your keymap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Setkeycodes) to see what key codes are in use.  Remember to pick a key code < 247.